# Nodejs: how can undefined variable evaluate to true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I've searched for this and come up with nothing. I must be doing something wrong, but can't work out what. I've got the following code:

```
var token = req.cookies.token;

// decode token
if (typeof token !== 'undefined' && token && token.trim()) {

    // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
    req.token = token;

    console.log("Token found");
    console.log("Token:" + token);

    next();

}
```

When running this, I get the following output:

```
0|app   | Token found
0|app   | Token:undefined
```

i.e. token evaluates to true, but then when I try to write it to the console it is undefined. My question is, how can the if statement evaluate to true if token is undefined?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to print `typeof token` :)

Comment: What does console.log(typeof token) prints?

Comment: typeof token = string apparently. I'm still not sure why this should be defined one minute and not the next?? thanks for your help.

Comment: @zazzy78 `undefined !== "undefined"`. The constant value and a string containing the constant's name aren't interchangeable, especially with truthiness. The latter is a string with `length > 0`, so it's truthy, regardless of the message its characters give you.

Comment: The word `'undefined'` is a non-empty string and is not `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

token is set as 'undefined', a string. perhaps when you save the cookie, that value is undefined

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I understand what is happening now, i.e. the token string is set to 'undefined' elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Except what everybody else said that undefined is string which means you will need to fix storing of token so it does not store undefined as string (not store it at all)

You also have unnecessary check in your if statement. You can get rid of typeof token !== 'undefined'  as if(token) will handle that case.